# Rails filter record on column value without association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two models with both have :phone column,

I'm trying to query Leads who don't have :phone present in User's Records

So if lead has 3 records with unique phones

```
Lead.last(3)
#<Lead>
    {
    :id => 1
    :phone => "9898989898" 
    },
#<Lead>
    {
    :id => 2
    :phone => "1212121212" 
    },
#<Lead>
    {
    :id => 3
    :phone => "3434343434" 
    }
```

and user has same :phone present

```
#<User>
{
:id => 95
:phone => "3434343434"
}
```

the record phone present in user's table should not come in query of Lead records
Please note that i don't want to add any relations or associations on this two Models.

Any help/suggestions appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with:

```
Lead.where.not(phone: User.select(:phone))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, never thought that solution would be this much simpler.